# Time evolution in a static magnetic field of a 2-level system that is actually a 3 level system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, linear-algebra

What I want to do is describe the time evolution of only two states of a spin 1 particle on the bloch sphere. However, I'm running into trouble because I don't know how to construct the hamiltonian for those two states, such that the time evolution operator is correct. I'll describe what I mean in more detail below:

I have a spin-1 particle, of which I'll describe the spin state as $m_S$. So there's three possibilities, $m_S = -1, 0, 1$. Now, if I want to describe how this spin behaves in a uniform static magnetic field, I simply write
\begin{equation}
{\cal H}_{0} = -\hbar \gamma_e B_0 \frac{\sigma_z}{2} = -\hbar \omega_0 \frac{\sigma_z}{2} =  \begin{pmatrix}
    -\frac{\hbar \omega_0}{2} & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & \frac{\hbar \omega_0}{2}
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Where $\sigma_z = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$

Using the usual exponential for the time evolution, one has $U = e^{-i{\cal H}_{0}t}$

Up to this point I'm fairly certain I'm doing it right, but now I want to do something where it gets a little fuzzy for me. Instead of looking at the system as a three level system, I only want to look at two of the levels ($m_S = 0$ and $m_S = -1$) so that I can look at the system on the Bloch sphere. However, how do I do this? I suppose I can just choose my basis and define
$
\left|0\right> = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    0
\end{pmatrix}$
$,
\left|1\right> = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    1
\end{pmatrix}$

However, how does one now describe the time evolution of these two states in a magnetic field, like I did with the three states before? I can't simply take the spin 1/2 pauli matrix, because the spin 0 state does not evolve in a magnetic field. I suppose I could only take the part of the hamiltonian that has to do with the 0 and -1 states, but then how would this time evolution work in a tensor product, if my states are described with two coordinates and the hamiltonian is a 2x3 matrix?

Comment: I wish I could get more clarity on your question. Why do you want to look at the Bloch sphere when the particle is a spin 1 particle ? What exactly is your motive ?

Comment: I apologize. What I want to do is use these two levels as a qubit, and it's easiest (in my opinion) to represent a qubit on the Bloch sphere, as I want to do rotations between the two levels and such.

Comment: I suggest you try taking a linear combination of eigenstates which means, you still have a sum 1X3 column but with one of the coefficients to be zero. I am not if you can reduce the state to 1X2 columns.

Comment: Hm alright, so if I correctly understand what you're saying is I'd use the Bloch sphere to depict only the 2nd and the 3rd row of my state vector, and (pictorially) ignore the first row (which in principle should stay zero as long as I stay between the other two levels)? And for calculations, I'd just use the three vector/3x3 matrices. That seems to make sense, I'll give it a shot, thank you

Comment: I'm afraid I get stuck though. If I take (0,1,0) as my 'up' state and (0,0,1) as my 'down' state on the bloch sphere, then how do I perform rotations of these two states? Do I simply take the expressions for a spin 1/2 particle, and extend the matrix to a 3x3 matrix in such a way that it leaves the first row of my column vectors untouched? That feels a bit like cheating, and I wouldn't know how to justify it.

Answer (score 1):

Well here is an attempt at the answer based on your comments and question.
Consider your state $ \left | \psi \right> $ be 
$$ \left | \psi \right> = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\left | 0 \right> +\left | -1 \right>) $$
Now int the $\mathbb{C}^3$ representation, this becomes
$$ [\left | \psi \right> ] =  \frac{1}{\sqrt2}
  \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   0  \\
   1  \\
   1  \\
  \end{array} } \right]
= \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \Bigg(  \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   0  \\
   1  \\
   0  \\
  \end{array} } \right]+
  \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   0  \\
   0  \\
   1  \\
  \end{array} } \right]\Bigg)
$$

Now the transformation ( in $SU(3)$ ) that will leave this kind of a vector without disturbing the first component.
$$ U = \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & a & b \\
   0 & c & d \\
  \end{array} } \right] 
$$

I think the justification would be with the fact that $SU(2) \subset SU(3) $.

Now, remember when two spin half particles are considered you add their angular momentum to obtain states with $j=0,1$ ?
The four states, if you want to get it listed :
$ \left | 00 \right>,\left | 1-1 \right> \left | 10 \right>,\left | 1+1 \right>$
in the $\left | jm \right>$ basis,and $ \left | \frac{-1}{2}\frac{1}{2} \right>,\left | \frac{-1}{2}\frac{-1}{2}\right> \left | \frac{1}{2}\frac{-1}{2} \right>,\left |\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2} \right>$ in the $\left | m_1m_2 \right>$ basis. And you know what the [CG coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients) are, connecting these two bases, now that itself will form you a map.

Your operators can be also be mapped in a similar fashion, and you can proceed with your calculations

**Note** : This is just an attempt at answering your question. I suggest you wait for (may be) better answers from better users.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think it's definitely headed in the right direction! I think the unitary matrix is more like what I need though, rather than the map. The problem with the map would be that I can't simply group together 0 and -1, for example, as they behave differently in the presence of magnetic fields, and I don't really see how one could treat that in this case. However, I'll go ahead and give both suggestions some thought (and work out some calculations), and see if they come up with results the way I would expect them to.

Comment: @user129412 : My bad, I didn't see about the magnetic field part in your question. I have edited the answer in that regard, please have a look again at it!